# No data на диаграмме библиотеки Pygal

Tags: python

сообщество **StackOverflow**! Пытаюсь построить диаграмму наиболее популярных *Python-проектов* с **GitHub'а** при помощи **pygal**, но почему-то при передаче в параметр **pygal.Bar().add** ссылки на массив, в котором хранятся словари с загруженными через **API GitHub** данными, при построении диаграммы выдает

> No Data

Но если передавать массив напрямую, то все отображается нормально. Буду признателен за помощь

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import NeonStyle as NS, LightenStyle as LS

#Создание вызова API и сохранение ответа.
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(url)
print('Код статуса - ', r.status_code)

#Сохранение ответа API в переменной.
response_dict = r.json()
print("Всего репозиториев: ", response_dict['total_count'])

#Анализ информации о репозиториях
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    #Получить описание проекта, если оно имеется.
    description = repo_dict['description']
    if not description:
        description = "Описание проекта отсутствует."
    plot_dict = {
        'Рейтинг' : repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'Описание' : description,
        'Ссылка' : repo_dict['html_url'],
        }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

#Построение визуализации.
my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=NS)

my_style.title_font_size = 20
my_style.label_font_size = 10
my_style.major_label_font_size = 12

my_config = pygal.Config()

my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.show_legend = False
my_config.truncate_label = 15
my_config.show_y_guides = False
my_config.width = 1000

chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)

chart.title = 'Наиболее популярные Python-проекты на GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в pygal словари, и соответственно он не может вам ничего построить, потому что нет массива данных.
Можно передать dict, но тогда вам надо заполнить поля `value` и `label`. И он сможет показать вам chart.

Например, это можно сделать вот так:

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import NeonStyle as NS, LightenStyle as LS

#Создание вызова API и сохранение ответа.
url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(url)
print('Код статуса - ', r.status_code)

#Сохранение ответа API в переменной.
response_dict = r.json()
print("Всего репозиториев: ", response_dict['total_count'])

#Анализ информации о репозиториях
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    #Получить описание проекта, если оно имеется.
    description = repo_dict['description']
    if not description:
        description = "Описание проекта отсутствует."
#    plot_dict = {
#        'Рейтинг' : repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
#        'Описание' : description,
#        'Ссылка' : repo_dict['html_url'],
#        }
    plot_dict = {                                   # <----
        'label': description,                       # <----
        'value': repo_dict['stargazers_count']
    }
    plot_dicts.append(plot_dict)

print(plot_dicts)
#Построение визуализации.
my_style = LS('#333366', base_style=NS)

my_style.title_font_size = 20
my_style.label_font_size = 10
my_style.major_label_font_size = 12

my_config = pygal.Config()

my_config.x_label_rotation = 45
my_config.show_legend = False
my_config.truncate_label = 15
my_config.show_y_guides = False
my_config.width = 1000

chart = pygal.Bar(my_config, style=my_style)

chart.title = 'Наиболее популярные Python-проекты на GitHub'
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.render_to_file('python_repos.svg')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как обычно невнимательность - главный враг(